# MongoDB OR operation questions

Tags: mongodb, or-operator

I am learning MongoDB myself, and I find myself in a weird situation. Here's the query #1

1. When I run `db.players.find({$or: [{"position":"Left Wing"}, {"position":"Right Wing"}]}).pretty()`, on my sample dataset, this is the result:

   ```
   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a245"),
   "position" : "Right Wing",
   "id" : 8465166,
   "weight" : 200,
   "height" : "6' 0\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://1.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8465166.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Seria, BRN",
   "age" : 37,
   "name" : "Craig Adams",
   "birthdate" : "April 26, 1977",
   "number" : 27


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a246"),
   "position" : "Right Wing",
   "id" : 8475761,
   "weight" : 195,
   "height" : "6' 2\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://1.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8475761.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Gardena, CA, USA",
   "age" : 23,
   "name" : "Beau Bennett",
   "birthdate" : "November 27, 1991",
   "number" : 19


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a247"),
   "position" : "Left Wing",
   "id" : 8471260,
   "weight" : 202,
   "height" : "6' 1\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://3.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8471260.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Meadow Lake, SK, CAN",
   "age" : 29,
   "name" : "Blake Comeau",
   "birthdate" : "February 18, 1986",
   "number" : 17


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a249"),
   "position" : "Right Wing",
   "id" : 8471703,
   "twitterURL" : "https://twitter.com/S9Downie",
   "weight" : 191,
   "height" : "5' 11\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://1.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8471703.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Newmarket, ON, CAN",
   "twitterHandle" : "S9Downie",
   "age" : 28,
   "name" : "Steve Downie",
   "birthdate" : "April 03, 1987",
   "number" : 23


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a24a"),
   "position" : "Right Wing",
   "id" : 8466393,
   "weight" : 205,
   "height" : "6' 1\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://2.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8466393.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Laval, QC, CAN",
   "age" : 35,
   "name" : "Pascal Dupuis",
   "birthdate" : "April 07, 1979",
   "number" : 9


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a24b"),
   "position" : "Right Wing",
   "id" : 8471887,
   "weight" : 189,
   "height" : "5' 11\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://1.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8471887.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Sollentuna, SWE",
   "age" : 28,
   "name" : "Patric Hornqvist",
   "birthdate" : "January 01, 1987",
   "number" : 72


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a24c"),
   "position" : "Left Wing",
   "id" : 8470543,
   "weight" : 195,
   "height" : "6' 0\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://3.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8470543.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Regina, SK, CAN",
   "age" : 35,
   "name" : "Chris Kunitz",
   "birthdate" : "September 26, 1979",
   "number" : 14


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a24f"),
   "position" : "Left Wing",
   "id" : 8474102,
   "twitterURL" : "https://twitter.com/DP_57",
   "weight" : 200,
   "height" : "6' 0\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://3.cdn.nhle.com/nhl/en/v3/photos/mugs/8474102.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Sherbrooke, QC, CAN",
   "twitterHandle" : "DP_57",
   "age" : 26,
   "name" : "David Perron",
   "birthdate" : "May 28, 1988",
   "number" : 39
   ```

   Sorry, formatting a JSON file is difficult. Please assume the larger gaps above as where the brackets were.
2. When I run `db.players.find({"position":"Left Wing"} || {"position":"Right Wing"}).pretty(),` the result is:

   ```
   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a247"),
   "position" : "Left Wing",
   "id" : 8471260,
   "weight" : 202,
   "height" : "6' 1\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://3.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8471260.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Meadow Lake, SK, CAN",
   "age" : 29,
   "name" : "Blake Comeau",
   "birthdate" : "February 18, 1986",
   "number" : 17


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a24c"),
   "position" : "Left Wing",
   "id" : 8470543,
   "weight" : 195,
   "height" : "6' 0\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://3.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8470543.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Regina, SK, CAN",
   "age" : 35,
   "name" : "Chris Kunitz",
   "birthdate" : "September 26, 1979",
   "number" : 14


   "_id" : ObjectId("57d9a212698d3e0bd0f5a24f"),
   "position" : "Left Wing",
   "id" : 8474102,
   "twitterURL" : "https://twitter.com/DP_57",
   "weight" : 200,
   "height" : "6' 0\"",
   "imageUrl" : "http://3.cdn.nhle.com/nhl/en/v3/photos/mugs/8474102.jpg",
   "birthplace" : "Sherbrooke, QC, CAN",
   "twitterHandle" : "DP_57",
   "age" : 26,
   "name" : "David Perron",
   "birthdate" : "May 28, 1988",
   "number" : 39
   ```

Why's this discrepancy, considering they're both `OR` operation? Please help me understand it.

Windows 10/MongoDB on IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding with little mongo knowledge.

- || operator command works in the below manner
- a || b -> if a is true it just passes value a to the db.players.find(a) and ignores b.
- here in your case 'a' refers to get the {"position":"Left Wing"} so it retrieves only "Left Wing" documents.
- where as $or: prepares indexes on each condition and fetches the combined results for "Left Wing" and "Right Wing".

Try the below commands on mongo shell, I think it gives some better idea.

```
> {$or: [(1==1), (2==1)]}
 [ true, false ]
> (1==1) || (2==1)
 true
> {$or: [(2==1), (1==1)]}
 [ false, true ]
> (2==1) || (1==1)
 true
```

Hope it helps.

**Thanks,

Rana**

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of `{"position":"Left Wing"} || {"position":"Right Wing"}` is a JavaScript expression that evaluates to `{"position":"Left Wing"}` because that term is truthy. So that's what you're actually passing into `find`, and that's why you're only getting the `"Left Wing"` documents in that query.

You can see this in the shell by doing:

```
> var query = {"position":"Left Wing"} || {"position":"Right Wing"}
> query
{ "position" : "Left Wing" }
```

But you can also simplify your `$or` query to use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) instead:

```
db.players.find({"position": {$in: ["Left Wing", "Right Wing"]}})
```